# Offline OpenStreetMap with vector maps for Windows Phone?

Tags: offline, maps, vector-graphics, windows-phone, openstreetmap

I am using an HTC 7 Pro and I am looking for an [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org/) app where I can download offline maps as **vector maps**.

I need OpenStreetMap because the maps are very good in my area of Argentina. (Google Maps is way too incomplete in my area of Argentina.)

The only apps with offline maps I know ([SimpleOSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Simple_OSM) and [xMaps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/XMaps)) do not provide offline vector maps.

Are there any apps that can provide this functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Windows Phone app [Vectorial Map](http://www.vectorialmap.com) uses offline vector maps. It is also available for iPhone, Android and Blackberry. It uses [OpenStreetMap maps in the Mapsforge format](http://download.mapsforge.org/), which you can download for free.