# Offline Vector Map for Windows Mobile

Tags: gps, maps, offline, navigation, windows-ce

I’d like to use an offline vector map (not bitmap) with more or less up-to-date map data on my Windows Mobile 6 Professional (Windows CE-based, *not* related to Windows Phone) device. (These devices typically have only 64 MiB RAM, which constraints them quite a bit.)

OpenStreetMap would be nice, but I’d not say no to commercial solutions.

My requirement is that I’d be able to add countries or even parts of countries (regions) to my Micro-SD card, which would then allow me to fully use the offline vector map, with and without(!) GPS reception. Navigation (turn-by-turn, or even just drawing me a suggested route on the map) is optional but would be nice. I’d want to be able to add other countries, or parts thereof, later, and to update the map data. My requirements are pretty Euro-centric, but I will need, for example, decent coverage of Bosna i Hercegovina for a planned vacation. (Which is one of the reasons for wanting this offline; roaming prices are large.)

The software also absolutely must allow for me to enter WGS84 coordinates in several formats, at least “decimal digits” (`d.dddddd,d.dddddd`) and “Geocaching standard” (`dd mm.mmm N d mmm.mmm E`). Bonus for functions like waypoint management, projection (X metres in Y degrees), and whatever is useful for some geocaching, although I also have other software for that.

Also optional but probably useful: public transportation information.

Navigation, if any, should be car for large scale (maybe include TMS (online) as an option), and include pedestrian for small scale navigation.

I need a 2D map (I get actually ill from 3D), north up, and vector (not bitmap; I have software for that, but OSM blocks MOBAC). With OSM, I’d like to have a layer similar to Mapnik (but ideally without some of the less useful information.)

I’ve looked at [the OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile), but most of the software listed either no longer exists, or is no longer developed in favour of an Android so-called “App”, or has got a website from which I cannot gather any information (e.g. by being written in Russian).

Comment: Related but no duplicate: [offline-openstreetmap-with-vector-maps-for-windows-phone](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/143/)

Comment: Indeed: Windows Phone is the software where current Desktop Windows is built on (yes it’s this way, not the other way around), while Windows Mobile uses Windows CE technology, which evolved alongside Win32 but is not related to it much. But thanks for the link. Most software from Windows Phone will not be reusable – even Java™ or Mobile dotNET software, due to the lack of RAM on Windows Mobile devices.

Comment: I do not want to discourage you, but as per my view of WindowsMobile platform (I still have WM devices), it can be spoken dead. Are you really bound to WindowsMobile with your solution?

Comment: @miroxlav yes I am, I find those multi-touch things unusable and unintuitive (that includes Android (worst of them all), iPhoneOS and BlackBerry), and I actually *like* Windows Mobile, it’s simple, easy to use and just works. My successor platform will be the [Neo900](http://neo900.org/) but that’s still a ways forward in time…

Comment: does [this app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/17577/67953) install on your device?

Comment: @svetlana that’s for Windows Phone, not Windows Mobile… though I don’t use the WM device currently

Answer (score 0):

Delorme had some kind of product offering in the US, but I don't know if it had an EU offering.  You could look for old copies on eBay.  No clue if it had vector maps though.  For the 2009 edition you had to cut out areas to save to the phone; I didn't like that very much, but it did work.  They also had a UMPC function for using a PC with low resolution as a GPS.  That may be an alternative for you.

Answer (score 0):

iGo or TomTom has SOME of the features you need. You will need to download PoI and other plugins for some of the functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Use OpenStreetMap
You can download the application maps.me that works offline
or
you can grab the map with any grabbers. I do it with mapbox.com - you choose the region, catch the data and get all the layers of map in vector

Comment: The question states that OpenStreetMap doesn't work on Windows Mobile.  Are you saying that things have changed since the question was first posted?

Comment: `maps.me` is not available for Windows Mobile.